# How to properly place x-axis labels (circular labels) in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I obtain my labels using the following script.

```js
const xAxis = (g) => g
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", 10)
  .call((g) => g.selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.range(0, 24)) // create an array of hour values
    .join("g")
      .each((d, i) => d.id = `hour-${i}`)
      .call((g) => g.append("path")
          .attr("stroke", "#000")
          .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.2)
          .attr("d", (d) => `
            M${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), innerRadius)}
            L${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), outerRadius)}
          `))
      .call((g) => g.append("path")
          .attr("id", (d) => `hour-${d}`)
          .datum((d) => [d * 60, (d + 1) * 60])
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .attr("d", ([a, b]) => `
            M${d3.pointRadial(x(a), innerRadius)}
            A${innerRadius},${innerRadius} 0,0,1 ${d3.pointRadial(x(b), innerRadius)}
          `))
      .call((g) => g.append("text")
        .append("textPath")
          .attr("startOffset", 6)
          .attr("href", (d) => `#hour-${d}`)
          .text((d) => d.toString().padStart(2, "0"))
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
          .attr("transform", (d) => {
            const angle = x(d * 60);
            const radius = innerRadius - 20; // reduce the radius to move the labels closer to the center
            return `rotate(${(angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90)}) translate(${radius},0) rotate(${(90 - angle * 180 / Math.PI)})`;
          })
      )
  );
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Labels 00 and 12 overlap with radial scales. How can I prevent it? I would expect the x-axis labels (circular labels) to NOT overlap with other labels and be at the center of their respective line.

Also, how can I make sure all labels look like 00, so that none of them are rotated? it mskes them hard to read.

My complete code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/uba054z9/

My CSV file looks like this

```
DATE_TIME,ID,HOUR,MINUTE,VALUE1,VALUE2,TIME,INSPECTION,seconds
2018-11-01 00:00:00,1,0,0,131.8403388480975,163.40706930229611,00:00:00,1,0
2018-11-01 00:20:00,1,0,20,128.66143180880016,182.4166850946821,00:20:00,1,20
2018-11-01 00:40:00,1,0,40,157.9838672230082,177.12826879097582,00:40:00,1,40
2018-11-01 01:00:00,1,1,0,154.74491894762372,177.02056153432287,01:00:00,1,60
2018-11-01 01:20:00,1,1,20,145.17425322202857,170.28572211898428,01:20:00,1,80
2018-11-01 01:40:00,1,1,40,86.33692934233684,161.306233500133004,01:40:00,1,100
2018-11-01 02:00:00,1,2,0,157.70472270832147,175.57007397898963,02:00:00,1,120
2018-11-01 02:20:00,1,2,20,92.04378773072385,152.758855696098315,02:20:00,1,140
2018-11-01 02:40:00,1,2,40,94.91482763887929,164.34713115356462,02:40:00,1,160
2018-11-01 03:00:00,1,3,0,150.58752716935703,152.573995003487525,03:00:00,1,180
2018-11-01 03:20:00,1,3,20,147.64763286003245,181.7346317353725,03:20:00,1,200
2018-11-01 03:40:00,1,3,40,152.00311766772614,169.43438782829136,03:40:00,1,220
2018-11-01 04:00:00,1,4,0,90.67568616871652,165.94364405219294,04:00:00,1,240
2018-11-01 04:20:00,1,4,20,127.6260776280666,154.41327889693226,04:20:00,1,260
2018-11-01 04:40:00,1,4,40,88.35193693321801,86.7514997924824,04:40:00,1,280
2018-11-01 05:00:00,1,5,0,99.44723697225662,61.81705113015809,05:00:00,1,300
2018-11-01 05:20:00,1,5,20,153.28490595395064,70.71671056760238,05:20:00,1,320
2018-11-01 05:40:00,1,5,40,139.53124376248127,86.96902617467873,05:40:00,1,340
2018-11-01 06:00:00,1,6,0,144.5960580946409,53.46091762212306,06:00:00,1,360
2018-11-01 06:20:00,1,6,20,110.05611978038519,73.32550566412914,06:20:00,1,380
2018-11-01 06:40:00,1,6,40,151.21482961729612,50.858838256056316,06:40:00,1,400
2018-11-01 07:00:00,1,7,0,127.88766918064593,52.45266678876003,07:00:00,1,420
2018-11-01 07:20:00,1,7,20,148.72830141013,60.496196118302194,07:20:00,1,440
2018-11-01 07:40:00,1,7,40,83.62908148257569,86.54612924908034,07:40:00,1,460
2018-11-01 08:00:00,1,8,0,113.49475177931873,59.15439348393694,08:00:00,1,480
2018-11-01 08:20:00,1,8,20,139.37377082538475,86.1347823168292,08:20:00,1,500
2018-11-01 08:40:00,1,8,40,104.5216263376223,86.92624219265554,08:40:00,1,520
2018-11-01 09:00:00,1,9,0,152.55680056900144,60.938994790632144,09:00:00,1,540
2018-11-01 09:20:00,1,9,20,140.38896796205978,56.19504976107255,09:20:00,1,560
2018-11-01 09:40:00,1,9,40,135.79579769996855,62.50941443441722,09:40:00,1,580
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tweak the `transform` of the last `append("text")` call.

1. Decrease the radius even more to place the labels closer to the center to avoid the overlap.
2. I think you need to remove the second `rotate` here to not rotate the labels. Not completely sure about this though.

   .attr("transform", (d) => {
   const angle = x(d * 60);
   const radius = innerRadius - 30; // reduce the radius to move the labels closer to the center
   return `rotate(${(angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90)}) translate(${radius},0)})`;
   })

It would be great if you could share a reproducible example on something like ObservableHQ or VizHub.

Comment: Changing radius was not helpful at all and removing rotating did not work well, too.